# Deriving stiffness matrix for FEM problem.

Tags: calculus, integration, weak-derivatives, finite-element-method

I have the 1D differential equation $-e^xu'' -e^xu' + u = f(x)$ with BC $u(0)=u(1)=0$ I am trying to come up with the $N\times N$ FEM matrix for this problem.

So first I get the weak formulation of the problem:

$$\int_\Omega -e^xu''\phi_i(x)-e^xu'\phi_i(x)+u\phi_i(x)= \int_\Omega f(x)\phi_i(x)$$

Normally I think you are supposed to use integration by parts to have only terms with a single derivative. But getting the differentiation by parts when I have 3 functions in the product is proving challenging for me.

Is there a different way (computer programs included) where I could get the stiffness matrix for the problem?

Comment: Suggestion: the first two terms form the product rule, as $(-e^x u')' = -e^x u'' -e^x u'.$

Comment: The stiffness matrix for a 1D FEM problem with linear shape functions can be obtained using the following formula:
$$K_{i,j}=\int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_i} k(x)\frac{d\phi_i}{dx}\frac{d\phi_j}{dx}dx$$
where $k(x)=-e^x$, $\phi_i(x)$ is the linear shape function for the $i$-th node, and $x_{i-1}$ and $x_i$ are the locations of the $i-1$-th and $i$-th nodes, respectively. The integrals can be computed numerically using quadrature rules, such as the Gauss-Legendre quadrature.

Comment: @rumathe interesting, do you happen to know a resource that proves that result?

Comment: "The Finite Element Method: Theory, Implementation, and Applications" by Mats G. Larson and Fredrik Bengzon or "Finite Element Procedures" by Klaus-Jürgen Bathe